# Relationship mapping in Hibernate Java - save owning side entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I have 2 tables

- User
- Url

I'm trying to create a relationship between said 2 tables. A user can have many urls, but a url can belong to only one user.

This sounds to me like a OneToMany relationship.

My User Entity is as follows(some code was removed as to not make it too long):

```
public class User{

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "user",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private final List<RssUrl> rssUrls = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addRssUrl(RssUrl rssUrl) {
        rssUrls.add(rssUrl);
        rssUrl.setUser(this);
    }

    public void removeComment(RssUrl rssUrl) {
        rssUrls.remove(rssUrl);
        rssUrl.setUser(null);
    }
```

My Url Entity is as follows(some code was removed as to not make it too long):

```
public class RssUrl {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User user;
```

I've been following a relatively simple guide which I've found [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

Now my question is: **How do I save the owning side entity?**

Say I already have a user created.

```
User user = getCurrentUserDetails();
```

I add a new url for that user

```
user.addRssUrl(rssUrl);
```

And now what?

I've tried

```
    User user = getCurrentUserDetails();
    user.addRssUrl(rssUrl);
    rssUrlRepository.save(rssUrl);
```

But that results in an errror:

```
org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing
```

---

Of course, I could be going about this all wrong, perhaps my relationship is not correct to begin with?

I'm very open to ideas.

Comment: Just Be aware of CASCADE.ALL. If you remove one URL from your database, because of CASCADE.ALL configuration, your related users will be deleted as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You configure the relation between `User` and `Url` correctly. It mainly complains when it saves an `Url` , its `User` is a new record.

The problem can be fixed if you save the `User` first :

```java
 User user = getCurrentUserDetails();
 user.addRssUrl(rssUrl);

 userRepository.save(user);
 rssUrlRepository.save(rssUrl);
```

But since you already configure `cascade` is ALL for `User` 's `Url` , all JPA operations applied on `User` will automatically applied to its `Url` too , which means you can simply do :

```java
 User user = getCurrentUserDetails();
 user.addRssUrl(rssUrl);

 userRepository.save(user);
```

Comment: You're correct. I can't believe I didn't try this earlier.